# Android SyncAdapter mechanism

Tags: php, android, sqlite, android-syncadapter

Can you please explain to me how should I implement the logic of syncing to my app?
I mean, I have the sync code, I have the services, the provider, everything, but I do not understand it (I have the sync code from an Android Programming (OReilly) tutorial).

So, I imagine, the sync should happen like this:

1. user starts the app, and is directed towards the login page, enters there a user and a password, then clicks LOGIN.
2. Now, my login method sends a HTTP request to my server side (remote mySQL+PHP), and on the server side a PHP file returns a token in a JSON (if the user+pass exist).
3. Now that I have the token in the app, I create an account (so I can use the sync feature of Android)
4. Then if login successfull, I start the mainActivity and carry on with the regular job of the app.
5. Now...

... so far, so good. My account appears in Accounts/Syncing

I Assume I should store the token on the server side (in the "users" remote table perhaps)
Then I guess, I should implement my sync logic. Now here is my question:
The sync logic, should it be something like this?

***Remote table1 structure:***
id,name,surname,dateofbirth,deleted

***Remote table2 structure:***
id, invoice_no,invoice_date, invoice_total,deleted

***Local (SQLite) tablex1 structure:***
_id,name,surname,dateofbirth,deleted

***Local (SQLite) tablex2 structure:***
_id, invoice_no,invoice_date, invoice_total,deleted

- Should I add to local tables a new field like "remote_id" (integer)?
- Then add to remote tables a new field called "synced" (boolean)  or maybe a "synced-timestamp"?
- And then have 2 methods: **pull()** *(for getting data from remote)* and **push()** *(for sending data to remote)*
- onPerformSync should I make verifications like this:

(for push)

```
      - send to remote a list with all records from tablex1 and tablex2 that have "remote_id" = null

      - on the server side, the PHP (after checking the token to be valid) will insert the new rows, with "synced" set to true
```

(for pull)

```
      - ask the remote to send back to me the list of all records that have the synced=false, then set them to true on remote.

      - process the returned rows and insert them locally in SQLite (including "remote_id")
```

Is this a good approach? Is it prone to duplicates or other problems? What should I use as a logic?

What do you do for syncing?

What logic do you recomend?

Thank you